# How to use Unity's Animation System and c# code to play an animation when a button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am starting to make a 2d mobile game where you cannot control the jump but It will activate according to a timer (For Example Every 3 seconds you will jump), but to make the game more interesting I have made it so you can glide, where the gravity is made weaker, therefore you fall faster, but right now you can constantly hold the glide button And I have a timer so that you can only control the glide for 2 seconds before the gravity reverts back to normal. But right now there is no way the player can tell exactly when the glide is going to end, So I want to add an animation like this: https://youtu.be/rThU_aIDTBY that will float above the player when he is gliding, so that the player will know when the glide ends. But I am completely new to animating in unity so I don not know how to make this animation play when the glide button is held down, Any help would be welocome and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please search about the animator compnent, you can create a trigger and change between animation states. You can't ask how to do something without try yourself.
When you'll try and have an issue without find any answer on internet, this is the time for a post here

Answer (score 0):

That video you linked is a Slider component, you can create one by right click on a UI gameObject and selecting UI/Slider.

Set the slider's "interactable" field to false, set the "maxValue" field to 2 (for 2 seconds) and then over the course of your animation, in your script set the "value" field to the number of seconds that have passed.

Then the last step is to just hide/show the gameObject it is attached to whenever the player clicks and unclicks the button.